# How to Replace Elements of a Matrix by Imposing Threshold in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a square matrix M in R whose all entries all real numbers lying between 0.5 to 1.9. I want to make adjacency matrix by imposing a condition that whenever each element is less than 0.6 then that element should replace by zero other wise element should replace by 1. This i want to do for all 141 threshold in
 `seq(0.5, 1.9, 0.01)` so that i can get 141 adjacency matrices. How can I get this? and how can I save or print all those matrices in R? Any help will be appreciated. Kindly bear with my poor knowledge in R :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `lapply` to loop over the values of "Seq1", create the binary matrix (`(M>=x)+0L`) and store it in a list ("lst")

```
lst <- lapply(Seq1, function(x) (M >=x)+0L)
length(lst)
#[1] 141
```

#### data

```
Seq1 <- seq(0.5, 1.9, 0.01)
set.seed(24)
M <- matrix(sample(Seq1, 10*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=10)
```

Comment: Dear Akrun, Thanx for your fast reply. Worked fine. I have no knowledge about `lapply`. But I will surely see this. Many thanks..

Comment: I tried before you said.. But It is saying I am less reputed member to give you a vote up.. But I will surely vote it up when I will become eligible for this..